# Passing multiple parameters in c# windows phone app using Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2))

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am creating a basic MCQ app where 2 MCQ's along with options are showed on a single page and the submit button shows the results on the second page in a textblock.

I am using `Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2))` method of navigation which can pass one parameter but, can't pass multiple parameters to the next page.

Here is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641

namespace MCQ
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }


        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {




            string ans1 = "";
            string ans2 = "";
            if (radioButton.IsChecked == true)
            {
                ans1 = "Answer 1 is correct";

            }
            else
            {
                ans1 = "Answer 1 is incorrect";
            }
            if (radioButton2.IsChecked == true)
            {
                ans2 = "Answer 2 is correct";

            }
            else
            {
                ans2 = "Answer 2 is incorrect";
            }


            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), ans1, ans2);

            //textBlock3.Text = ans1 + " & " + ans2; ;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

I get the error cannot convert from string to windows.ui.xaml.media. navigation.transitioninfo on the second parameter i.e. ans2.

Any help would be appreciated or an alternate way to pass parameters to next page.
THanks!

Comment: have you tried creating a new class object with all your variables in there and passing that object?

Comment: Personally, I always use a string. If I have several parameters I have a representation similar to URI query string : param1=value1&param2=value2. Remember that your parameter object must be serializable, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_

Comment: @SimonPrice has a point. It's better to implement singleton object

Comment: A better option is to create JSON objects and pass it as json strings. This can be achieved using Newtsonsoft nuget packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was server error due to mod security. It got solved. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class with 2 properties and set the properties to the text block values. Then you pass this object when you navigate.

Create the payload class:

```
public class Payload
{
 public string ans1 { get;set;}
 public string ans2 { get;set;}
}
```

Then populate the payload class:

```
Payload payload = new Payload();
payload.ans1 = textblock1.Text;
payload.ans2 = textblock2.Text;
```

Then when you call Navigate pass your instance of payload like this:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage),payload);
```